# Arbitrary-precision arithmetics in APL

Tags: apl

What is the easiest way to do arbitrary-precision (integral) arithmetics in APL?

Any known libraries?  Or are you supposed to “inline” the operations (and how)?

Comment: I'd help if you mention which dialect/implementation of APL you want to use.

Comment: If you happen to use Dyalog APL and you know that the "arbitrary precision" numbers won't exceed 34 digits, `⎕FR←1287⋄⎕PP←34` is enough for exact integer arithmetic.

Comment: NARS2000 has big fractional, so for +-/* has already big number integer (but not function as sqrt for big integer)… with some function one can use big fractional as big float too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dyalog APL includes the operator [`big`](http://dfns.dyalog.com/n_big.htm) in the [dfns workspace](http://dfns.dyalog.com/n_contents.htm) which allow arbitrary-precision arithmetic:

```
      'big'⎕CY'dfns'
      1234567890 ×big 9876543210
12193263111263526900
```

NARS2000 has built-in support: A suffix `x` indicates eXtended precision:

```
      1234567890 × 9876543210x
12193263111263526900
```